# How i can use html <form> using redux?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I do not use html  in form, because when I use and I click on `<button type = "button" className = "button button2" onClick = {() => this.login ()}> logar </ button>`, the page of a refresh and the error message some. But when I do not use it, this message appears to me in the console: [DOM] Password field is not contained in a form: (More info: https :// goo.gl/9p2vKq)

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react'
import  {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import ActionCreator from '../redux/actionCreators'

import styled from 'styled-components'

import Button from './elements/Button'

const BodyLogin = styled.div`
#formulario{
    max-width: 850px
}`



import  {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'



class ScreensLogin extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state = {
          form: {
              email: '',
              passwd: '',
          }        
      }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
      if (this.props.auth.error){
          this.props.reset()
      }      
  }
  handleChange = field => event => {
      const form = {
          ...this.state.form
      }
      form[field] = event.target.value
      this.setState({form})
  }
  login = () => {   
      const {email, passwd} = this.state.form
      this.props.login(email, passwd)
  }

  render(){
      return (
          <Fragment>  
              <BodyLogin> 
                <form>   //this is my problem       
                  <div className='form-group mx-auto' id="formulario">
                      <div className="input-group">
                          <div className="input-group-prepend">
                              <span className="input-group-text" id="">Email</span>
                          </div>
                          <input className="form-control" autoComplete='on' value={this.state.form.email} type="text" onChange={this.handleChange('email')} ></input>
                      </div>
                      <div className="input-group  mt-5 mb-5">
                          <div className="input-group-prepend">
                              <span className="input-group-text" id="">Senha</span>
                          </div>
                          <input className="form-control" autoComplete='on' value={this.state.form.passwd} type="password" onChange={this.handleChange('passwd')} ></input>
                      </div>       
                      <Button>
                          {<button type="button" className="button button2 " onClick={() => this.login()}>logar</button>}
                      </Button><br/><br/>
                      {this.props.auth.isAuth && <Redirect to={'/'}/>}

                      {
                          this.props.auth.error && <p className="text-danger">{this.props.auth.errorMessage}</p>            
                      }
                      {   
                          this.props.auth.isSigningin && <p className="text-info">Carregando...</p>
                      }  
                  </div>  
              </form>
              </BodyLogin>       
          </Fragment>
      )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
      auth: state.auth
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
      login: (email, passwd) => dispatch(ActionCreator.signinRequest(email,passwd)),
      reset: () => dispatch(ActionCreator.resetError())
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ScreensLogin)
```

Have some problem don't using the tag ?

Comment: Why you want to use form?

Answer (score 0):

You are using [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) component.

remove onclick from the button

```
<button type="button" className="button button2 " onClick={() => this.login()}>logar</button>
```

to

```
<button type="button" className="button button2">logar</button>
```

and in your form

```
<form onSubmit={this.login}>
```

this way you are actually submitting the form,

on other side you can pass event in button like this

```
<button type="button" className="button button2 " onClick={(e) => this.login(e)}>logar</button>
```

and in login function

```
login = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
      const {email, passwd} = this.state.form
      this.props.login(email, passwd)
  }
```

This way you can tell the form that I have handled submission of the form you do not need to do anything.

Comment: Thanks man, the primary option doesn't work for my problem, but the second is perfect for use the tag <form>. Is there any difference in use or not of the html `<form>` tag?

Comment: @JoseAlves you do not need form tag as you are handling it at client side, or if you want you have this two options.  I mostly use it to add the classes and indicate the form pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.